# Endless 'Loading...' message after Login in Sugar 7.2.1

Tags: sugarcrm

I am using the latest commercial version of SugarCRM, with 7.2.1 in Ubuntu 14.04.

I have logged-in to the sugar and it shows Endless 'Loading...' message. And there is one Fatal Error in my console i.e., `TypeError: error.payload is undefined at cache/include/javascript/sugar_sidecar.min.js?v=v05JhcpoUqgUDSTVs1g86g on line 599"`

Answer (score 1):

I've seen this endless 'Loading...' message appear when some of the file & folder permissions are incorrectly set. The article here has resolved it for me: http://support.sugarcrm.com/04_Find_Answers/02KB/02Administration/100Install/Required_File_System_Permissions_on_Linux/

Ben.

Answer (score 0):

Endless loading can be caused by a number of things, probably all of them JavaScript issues. The last few I encountered had to do with accessing the cached javascript files. Make sure you have mod_rewrite enabled if you're using Apache, and that .htaccess has the RewriteBase setting correctly pointing to the site. Also check config.php that site_url is correct.

Answer (score 0):

The SugarCRM PHP code is horrendous and generates loads of *errors* (warnings/notices/etc.)

I would add the following, either in your Apache settings or the .htaccess file in the root directory of SugarCRM.

```
# Avoid all those strict warnings
php_value error_reporting 0
```

This technically turns off all the warnings and notices, some of which would be transformed to errors as your question seems to show.